# Icons and applications not functioning properly after suspend

Tags: suspend, lenovo

When my laptop is suspended, after I turn it back on many different things act differently than intended. At first I couldn't even log in because of the sign in page: there was no indication that I was actually typing anything and the icons and text didn't display. I disabled the screen lock on suspend but the problem persists in other ways.

Some icons on my dock & the top bar use a placeholder icon, and I can not open any applications.. even terminal. The mouse also displays as a placeholder square if it's hovering over something.

If I already had an app open, they seem to randomly close after a minute or so - at least, Firefox did so. I can't even shut the laptop down using the buttons on the top right. Usually pressing any of those menu buttons causes a crash error. The only way to fix the bug is to shut down my laptop and turn it back on again, using the physical button. As you can imagine this is pretty inconvenient.

I got this laptop a few days ago and only set it up yesterday. It was NOT having these issues yesterday so I must have done something but I have no idea what it could be! I only installed LibreOffice suite and a few config files for Firefox extensions/bookmarks.

I'm not very tech savvy so I apologize if my descriptions were poor. If there's any additional information I should provide let me know. Thank you in advance.

Laptop model: Lenovo Ideapad 1 15AMN7

Ubuntu version: 22.04.3 LTS

I also have an AMD graphics card.

Edited to provide some more information and clarity.